Unwanted outline appear in render
first time post here,
English is not my first language so I will try my best to describe the issue I am having.
So I was making a specific city/landscape using addon blosm, I like the looks of uneven geo with flat shading so I decimated(collapse 0.25) the original terrain and simply turn it to "shade Flat", then I start noticing those lines appear.

I thought I was something wrong but I check the original terrain or shade flat but they both have some issue


There is nothing special on material, I feel is something very simple and stupid but I never had this before, please help, thanks for your time.
--update--
this is the clean file without overlay

issue shows on final render

eevee

eevee seems fine, I might do something wrong with the render setting?
upload project here

Is there a chance of a duplicate mesh in nearly the same place as the first?

I see objects "Terrain.001" and "Terrain_envelope" there... could it be they are interfering with each other?

The first collection is hidden in the viewport but not in render

It could be the viewport shading options or the overlays. Does disabling the overlays entirely removes the issue? Are the outlines visible in rendered preview?

@TheLabCat :Deleted everything else still there tho..

@GordonBrinkmann : I dont think so since I cleaned up the project the issue remains

@Lauloque : turn off overlay still there, and final render has it too.
the issue seems only happen in cycles tho so I am wondering is the render setting, will post some screenshots.

You are simply dealing with ridiculously high dimension values here so Blender has a hard time calculating edge normals precisely enough for smooth shading, because very high values result in loss of precision in floating point operations.
If you look at your original terrain object, I am not talking about the dimensions of the object itself with over 18 × 18 kilometers (although a smaller object might be better, too, but maybe you want some real world scale), but look at the Location: it says X, Y and Z are 0 meters - so it is located at the world center.

But is it really? If I now right-click on the terrain and choose Set Origin > Origin to Geometry which places the object origin within the mesh, it suddenly shows very different values: the terrain is almost 5 million meters(!) away on X and about -10.6 million meters(!) away on the Y axis. Modeling real world scale can be nice, but that's kind of extreme. Note that only changing the origin gives a very (very) slight improvement already since the relative distance between origin and mesh is now not as ridiculously high as it was before.

If I now also press Alt+G to clear the location so that the terrain with its new (mesh-based) origin gets set back to X/Y/Z = 0 m, then the lines disappear:

The only shading issues left there are just caused by the mesh having very sharp angles there which could not be smoothed better, for example in the top left of the screenshot there is a spiked "mount" with a high vertex close to other very low vertices as indicated below. Similar things occur in the other areas where the mesh seems less smooth, more extreme height differences leading to sharp angles or very narrow thin faces where vertices are almost touching other edges.

At the end, just to give you a sense of scale: from the world center to the new origin of the offset terrain it is a distance of around 11,674 km which means, if the world center would be at the North Pole of our Earth, you could travel down to the Amazon rain forest or Australia on the other side with such a distance.


I guess Blosm bring the date in real world location/scale, this helps a lot, thank you so much!!
